# ifconfig in QNX gives inet:0.0.0.0?

Tags: ethernet, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I have been trying to setup Ethernet connection between Ubuntu Host and QNX target. I have booted up the board and able to run shell commands using **Minicom**. When I give ifconfig it displays inet as 0.0.0.0.

Required clarification:

I could manually setup my ip address using ifconfig en0 . Is this the way we have to set IP address in QNX?
(or)

QNX automatically detects host IP address, once ethernet connection is established.

FYI
Host: Ubuntu 12.04
Target: QNX Neutrino SDP 6.6
Board: iMx6sabre AI/ARD board

Comment: There are many ways to configure your IP address, which are dependent in how your runtime is configured. For example, someone might choose to simply hardcode an IP address in '/etc/rc.d/rc.local'. Or you could use netmanager with an appropriately configured '/etc/net.cfg'. Need more details to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "ifconfig fec0 " to configure the ip

Answer (score 0):

Type: " vi /etc/net.cfg " :
Modify the IP address or IP mask
(Use arrow keys to move cursor, "xx" to delete, "i" to insert, "Esc" to change mode)
Press " Esc ".

Then type " :wq " to save the file (or " :q " to leave the file without saving).

Then restart the target:
Type: " shutdown -f "
https://www.opal-rt.com/KMP/index.php?/article/AA-00787/0/How-to-modify-the-IP-address-or-mask-on-a-QNX-or-Redhat-target-through-telnet.html